# Difference between scanf("%[^\n]") and scanf("%s")?

Tags: c, string, scanf, newline, whitespace

I have read about the behavior of scansets. By studying and testing, I encountered an issue.

Doesn´t `scanf("%[^\n]")` behave the same like `scanf("%s")`?

`scanf("%s")` is consuming characters until a white space character such as the `\n`-character is found in `stdin`. So the result should be exactly the same as `scanf("%[^\n]")`.

---

For example:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%99[^\n]s", str);
```

In comparison to:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%99s",str);
```

---

So my Questions are:

1. Isn´t the behavior the same because `scanf("%s")` stops at trailing white space characters such as the newline character?
2. Why should I implement `scanf("%[^\n]")` when `scanf("%s")` aleady does the same?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To begin with the format `%[^\n]s` is looking for a literal `s` in the input stream, while `%s` doesn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: And the literal `s` will never match since the next character in the input after the `%[^\n]` scan set completes is a newline (or EOF has been reached).  So, `"%[^\n]s%d"` will never match the number.  Also, scan sets are one of three conversion specifiers that do not skip white space — the other two are `%c` and `%n`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why is the format string `"%[^\n]s"` looking for the literal `s` for skipping? I´ve tested it with the input of `This is a string`and it is given me the output of `This is a string` for `str`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why is the format string `"%[^\n]s"` looking for the literal `s` for skipping? I´ve tested it with the input of `This is a string`and it is given me the output of `This is a string` for `str`?

Comment: The `%[` format ends at the closing `]`. There's no `s` in the format specifier.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But you said that in your previous comment: `the format %[^\n]s is looking for a literal s in the input stream,..`

Comment: Yes it does, as long as the stream is still valid. If you press the "end of file" keyboard-shortcut then you close the stream and nothing more can be read. That's actually a good idea for a new question, if you can't find a duplicate already. It is however unrelated to this specific question.

Comment: To demonstrate that `%[…]` is complete and the `s` is an interloper with no business there, you need to look for more than one value.  For example, `char str[100]; char nl; if (scanf("%99[^\n]s%c", str, &nl) != 2) { …the input did not contain an unread 's'… }`.  You can't detect matching failures in trailing literal characters such as the `s` in `%[^\n]s` directly.  It's the sort of stuff that makes `scanf()` something to avoid — see [A Beginners Guide Away From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: And if you've learned enough to spot the (over-?)simplification in my previous observation about "the input did not contain an unread 's'", then my mission is complete; you've learned how tricky `scanf()` can be.

Comment: https://ideone.com/6WTQtH

Comment: @pmg Yes, thank you very much. Looking backwards this anyhow was a stupid question. I came here back to make it clearer what I meant originally. I didn´t encountered the important difference between the `\n` and the other white space characters as well not that `%[^character]` will read characters until the provided *character* inside of the negated scanset is found, including other white space characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be under the mistaken impression that scanset is some sort of modifier to `%s`, as evidenced in your example:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
```

This is a scanf format string that will always fail matching the literal `'s'` at the end.

Rather, `%[` is a completely different conversion specifier from `%s`. `%s` consumes and ignores any initial whitespace before starting, then stops at whitespace. `%[` does not ignore leading whitespace at all and only stops at a non-matching character — it does not treat whitespace specially.

Comment: Thank you for these informations. It seems that i´ve given a wrong example of what i wanted to ask really. My question is more about the scanset of [\n] itself. Isn´t it redundant, because `scanf()` stops scanning for the according format string at white space characters such as `\n` by default? Why shall i than implement this scanset, if it is already behave in this way by default?

Comment: Why is the format string `"%[^\n]s"` fail matching the literal `s` for skipping? I´ve tested it with the input of `This is a string`and it is given me the output of `This is a string` for `str`?

Comment: `stops scanning for the according format string at white space charact` - This is not true. Scan for `%[s]`. You are scanning for `%[^\n]`, so the string `This is a string` is whole eaten by it, because there are no newlines in it.. If you would scan ex. `%[^\n]s%c` with ex. `"string\nanything"`, then `%[^\n]` will match `"string"`, `s` will fail to match, as the next character is `\n` and `scanf()` will return with `1`. The `%c` will not match anything

Comment: `Why shall i than implement this scanset, if it is already behave in this way by default?` - because `%s` stops at first whitespace character, while `%[^\n]` stop at first newline character. So if you want a whole line, you do `%[^\n]`. If you want the first word, you do `%s` or equivalent `%[^\t\n\v\f\r ]`

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, i´ve been mistaken and confused `\n` with just white space ' '. i think you finally guided me in the right direction. Thank you very much. :-) One last question, assume i want to get that `\n`out of `stdin` with one format string and want to scan characters thereafter, with the same scanf()-statement. Which one should i use? Something like `"%*[\n]"?

Comment: I guess you want `scanf("\n")`. Or somewhat equivalent `int c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) { error(...); } if (c != '\n') { ungetc(c); }`. The `%*[\n]` would read a number of newline characters and not store them anywhere. So `%*[\n]` would also read empty lines. The `' '` is a space. A ["white space"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) is any of `"\t\n\v\f\r "` (in the default locale).